# OPENVPN server windows 10 NAT and firewall setup

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, nat, windows-firewall

I have problem with ping and File and Printer Sharing.The only way is disable firewall in the server.
This is my configuration of the openvpn server:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
dev-node VPNserver
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
keepalive 10 120
max-clients 3
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log-append  openvpn.log
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify 1
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
route-delay 5
route-method exe
```

I can ping now next inserted in the firewall this rule:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow
```

but not see File and Printer Sharing.

Answer (score 0):

delete this and add a route to the TAP (server side)

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="ICMP Allow incoming V4 echo request" protocol=icmpv4:8,any dir=in action=allow



route -p add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 10.8.0.1 metric 50 if [number of tap device in route print]
```

5...ff ff ff ff ff ff ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9

```
route -p add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 10.8.0.1 metric 50 if 5
```

but server can't ping clients.
Is real the correct solution ?

Answer (score 0):

end solution  add firewall openvpn.exe udp open and in the server config

```
route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.8.0.1
```